# Laravel 5.2 Filter Lists by user or Show all lists from User with Eloquent

Tags: laravel, join, filter, eloquent, foreign-key-relationship

Okey, I'm newbie in Laravel and I want to do a function in my controller that returns a JSON with the all lists of one user, i want to filter users by email, that isn't the primary key, but I'm having a lot of problems here, and the documentation of laravel  didn't explain nothing about this.

Okey so i have a class User with this atributes and relationships:

**User.php**

```
protected $fillable = [
    'nom', 'email', 'password', 'data_de_naixament', 'sexe', 'type', 'imatge_usr', 'codi_postal'
];

public function lists()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\List');
}
```

And another class List:

**List.php**

```
protected  $fillable = ['nom_llista', 'id_user'];

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'id_user');
}
```

So I know that I have to do a JOIN and compare the input parameter with the email colum of the User table but I can not get it because they do not understand at all the syntax eloquent.

I'm able to do a function that store all lists and then filtering by email, but this isn't efficient if I have 2000 lists for example.

Hope you can help me and sorry for my poor English.

Comment: If you do `$user->whereEmail('email@example.com')->first()->lists()` you will get all the lists for this user. Is this what you're trying to do?

Comment: It has not worked at all, "data" returns null, but the answer below has worked, thanks anyway!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read the documentation

To retrieve information: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#retrieving-multiple-models

To convert a collection to json: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-tojson

Joining Models:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations

In other words your code could be like

```
$users = User::where('email', $emailYouAreLookingFor)->with('lists')->get()->toJson();
```

Comment: It works but i had issues with the name id_user, i changed the name to user_id and it works now, thank you!!

Comment: Great, but it wasn't neccessary, you can specify the name of the foreign and local keys  https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships    [return $this->hasMany('App\Comment', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');]